# How do I update every row of a particular column with values from another column?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, sql-insert

I am trying to update a column called software_id with a possible three values from a lookup table. So update user softwares software id column with the values from the softwares table of the id column. But there are only three rows in the softwares table. In the user softwares table there are over 1000. But when I run the query below only three rows get updated and the rest are left as null.

So the softwares id column is number and goes 1,2,3 and the user_sofwares software_id column is all null.

When I run the following query.

```
UPDATE user_software c 
SET sotware_id = (
                  SELECT DISTINCT id
                  FROM softwares
                  WHERE id = c.id
                  );
```

Only the first three rows of the destination table get updated. I want every row on the user_softwares column to be updated with either 1,2 or 3. So it should be 1,2,3,1,2,3 for example.

I keep getting this error whenever i tried to update all rows

```
Error report - ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `MERGE` statement:

```
MERGE INTO (SELECT software_id, 1, ora_hash(ROWID, 2) + 1 AS fake_id
              FROM user_software) u_soft
USING (SELECT DISTINCT id    
         FROM softwares) sftw
   ON (sftw.id = u_soft.fake_id)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET u_soft.software_id = sftw.id;
```

(considering your matches are unique)

Comment: this only updates three rows

Comment: How many are the distinct ids in `softwares` and how many of the `user_software` records do have id set? If your  `user_software`  are empty there is no remedy for assigning a proper id without a good deal of randomness and it just seems like a design flaw.

Comment: there are three software rows and user sofware column software_id is null. I want it to be random, any values of 1,2,3 from the id column of the softwares table

Comment: the id from the softwares table is the pk so there all unique

Comment: I did a workaround that could implement something like that, see the updated answer (I am assuming user_software.id is a number, adjust that if needed.

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-00904: "U_SOFT"."SOTWARE_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: u_soft.software_id = sftw.id; in the last row

Comment: thats the same as the current last row

Comment: Because I updated the post as well, it was missing a T

Comment: I had to add an extra ) here WHERE ID = soft.id) sftw but its still not working

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-01446: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.
01446. 00000 -  "cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc."
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: the id column contains a number

Comment: Remove the rowid from the query and replace it with any column or constant.

Comment: still doesnt work

Comment: ah, it's because of the exist in the subquery of the using clause... It's supposed to look for ids in user_software, but they are nulls. Remove it as well, since it will just return nothing at all.

Comment: still nope, just leave it, thanks for your help anyway

Comment: I created some dummy tables and tested it. Check the last adjustment.

Comment: perfect, what was the issue?

Comment: We used a subquery instead of the whole table in order to generate the fake_id, but didn't include the column that we actually want to update, since the subquery returns only the columns listed and therefore it needed to be added in order to have it updated. You can mark the answer as accepted if it satisfies your needs.

Comment: will do  it now thanks